# Is there a way to collapse multiple functions at once but not all of them in vscode?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sections, code-organization

I want to group multiple lines of CSS code into a single collapsible section, is there a way to do that in vscode?

[image]

I tried to use brackets but that didnt work. I tried other things as well but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code supports folding regions for markers if the language of the file [have markers defined](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding).

For CSS, by default its markers is defined as `/*#region*/` and `/*#endregion*/`:

```
/* #region Header */
.nav {
  width: 40px
}

#Boutons {
  width: 30px;
}
/* #endregion */

/* #region Footer */
.footer {
  height: 30px;
}

.footer p {
  height: 30px;
}
/* #endregion */
```

[image: folding regions opened]
[image: folding regions folded]

For other languages that doesn't have default markers defined, you would need to follow all steps to [create a language extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features), and [define markers in `language-configuration.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#folding). For example, the following official example creates folding markers for `//#region` and `//#endregion`.

```json
{
 "folding": {
    "markers": {
      "start": "^\\s*//\\s*#?region\\b",
      "end": "^\\s*//\\s*#?endregion\\b"
    }
  }
}
```

...Or alternatively, use the new [Create/Remove Manual Folding Ranges from Selection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_fold-selection) commands. (`Ctrl+K Ctrl+,` and `Ctrl+K Ctrl+.`) These manual folding arrows will stick around even if you edit the code. However, the drawback is that they couldn't be tracked by source control (not that I am aware of). Also, be aware that there is no visual difference when it overwrites the default folding providers (like the arrows for each selector).

[image: Fold by manual folding ranges]

Comment: The question was about VSCode not Visual Studio. Does this answer apply to VSCode as well?

Comment: It's a typo, I've updated the answer. This answer is for VS Code, though the first half of the answer will be applicable to most IDE I assume.